# Load multiple models in a controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to load multiple models in a particular function in a controller?

Expecting repeatatively ***$this->loadModel('ModelName')*** method.

Comment: What could be the case, you want to load multiple models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved my problem, it's a simple way by passing an array of ModelNames in `$this->loadModel();` function.

```
$this->loadModel('model1', 'model2', 'model3', ...);
```

And you want to load multiple models for whole controller then you can :

```
public $uses = array('model1', 'model2', 'model3', .... );
```

Comment: for me I have used "$this->loadModel" in 2 places for multiple models but base class it's working but for the child class it's only loading the first model only. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

If you only have one or two models, the easiest way is to call `loadModel` once or twice. Here is a one line code which should work (not tested) for you if you have multiple models:

```
array_map([$this, 'loadModel'], ['Model1', 'Model2', 'Model3']);
```

Anyway, if you really have a lot of models to load manually, maybe consider redesigning your project...

Answer (score 2):

Yes your method is correct

```
$this->loadModel('model1', 'model2', 'model3', ...);
```

And if you want to load multiple methods for the whole controller , In that case you can use this in the controller class

```
public $uses = array('model1','model2','model3', .... );
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
public function initialize(){
  $this->Model = $this->loadModel('modelClass')
}
```

You can replace Model and modelClass to your case

Answer (score 0):

$this->loadModel('model1', 'model2', 'model3', ...);

THIS IS NOT THE WAY ....
If you want to load multiple model in a single line then you have to use this..

> Blockquote
>   public $uses = array('model1','model2','model3', .... );
>   Blockquote

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS.